# Show/hide text with show more/less button angular 6

Tags: html, angular6

I have long descriptions.

In html:

`<div class="description" >{{ user.description }}</div>`

User is a class which contain description which is string. I get descriptions from server with a get() method on HttpClient. I would like to add `read more` button after few words of each description on my page. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: How many characters/words do you wanna show initially?

Comment: For example 5 words

Comment: use `moreClicked ? your string : your string.substr(0, 20)...`

Comment: Can You write sth more?

Answer (score -1):

The best way is with PHP.

```
<?php
$string=$_GET['description'];
if(strlen($string)>100){
 //show variables from first to the 100th.
 $substring=substr($string,0,100);
 echo $substring;
 ?>...<button type="button">read more</button><?php
}
?>
```

Comment: But i have to do this only with Html, scss and angular ts